# Calculate the Better Value between Two Different Products

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a code that will calculate the better value between two different product sizes

(E.g. a $10 for a 10g block of butter, or $15 for a 20g block of butter)

Right now, I only know how to collect the information, but I do not have a single idea on how to display which items has better value, worse value or equal value as the other product.
Here is my code so far:

```
a = int(input('Cost of first product($): '))
b = int(input('Cost of second product($): '))
c = int(input('Mass of first product(grams): '))
d = int(input('Mass of second product(grams): '))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the last part of your code that will display your results:

```
s = (a/c)
r = (b/d)
if (s>r):
  print('Product two is better value at', r,'$/g.')
elif (s<r):
  print('Product one is better value at', s,'$/g.')
else:
  print('These products are the same value.')
```

So, overall, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
a = int(input('Cost of first product($): '))
b = int(input('Cost of second product($): '))
c = int(input('Mass of first product(grams): '))
d = int(input('Mass of second product(grams): '))
s = (a/c)
r = (b/d)
if (s>r):
  print('Product two is better value at', r,'$/g.')
elif (s<r):
  print('Product one is better value at', s,'$/g.')
else:
  print('These products are the same value.')
```

Comment: Well, because the OP uses integers it might be interesting to evaluate the remainder in case of equality. And a test for c*d == 0 might be a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the ratios `price/mass`

```
if (a / c) < (b / d):
    print("first product better")
else:
    print("first product better")
```

To generalize the idea, you can save in an array the pairs `price-mass` then find the minimum of them

```
nb = 3
products = []
for i in range(nb):
    price = int(input(f'Cost of product n°{i + 1}($): '))
    mass = int(input(f'Mass of product n°{i + 1} ($): '))
    products.append((price, mass))

better = min(products, key=lambda pm: pm[0] / pm[1]) # pm is tuple price-mass
print(better)
```

Answer (score 0):

to calculate something use + - % / everything is possible with python for example:

```
result = ((a + b) / 12 ) * 20 #.... Whatever you want to calculate
```

To print something for the user use :

```
print(f" text to display {vriable_to_display}")
```

Maybe it's better to read some documentation and do simple exercises for variables and then jump back to this exercise
  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When you have a particular thing that has multiple attributes, it's usually easier to keep track of it as a set of values in a tuple than as multiple variables, and even easier if you use a `NamedTuple` (which lets you give a value to each name so you don't need to keep track of them by the order they appear in).

Similarly, when you have multiple things to keep track of, it's easier to keep track of them in a collection (usually a list, but sometimes a dict).

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Product(NamedTuple):
    """Data about a particular product."""
    name: str
    cost: float  # cost in dollars
    mass: float  # mass in grams


# Get a list of products to compare.
products = [
    Product(
        str(i+1),
        float(input(f"Cost of product {i+1} ($): ")),
        float(input(f"Mass of product {i+1} (g): ")),
    )
    for i in range(int(input("How many products do you want to compare? ")))
]

# Sort by cost per mass ratio and print results.
products.sort(key=lambda p: p.cost / p.mass)
for p in products:
    print(f"{p.name}: ${p.cost} for {p.mass}g = ${p.cost/p.mass:.2f}/g")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply just do:

```
a = int(input('Cost of first product($): '))
b = int(input('Cost of second product($): '))
c = int(input('Mass of first product(grams): '))
d = int(input('Mass of second product(grams): '))
if ((a/c) > (b/d)):
  print('Product 1 has better value at', (b/d), '$/g.')
elif ((a/c) < (b/d)):
  print('Product 2 has better value at', (a/c), '$/g.')
else:
  print('Both these products have the same value.')
```